# How can I access the controls from another running window form in c#

Tags: c#

Actually, I am a newbie for C#. In my program, I got two window forms.Each window forms have one label and one activate button.Once I start(load) the program,two window forms will pop-up together.My intention is when I click on the form1 activate button,my form1 label's back colour will change to "green"(to let user know this form1 is activated).Up to here I can write the soft code.But when I click on the form2 activate button,form1 will no longer active, my form2 will be activated and form2 label's back colour will also change to "green".Since form1 is no longer active,I would like to change my form1 label's back colour to red.How can I change it?

How I write my program so far.

In form1 activate button click
1.form1 label's back colour = Colour.green // to let user know form1 is activate upon               button click
2. form2 f2 = new form2();
   f2.(form2 label's).BackColour = Colour.red

There is no change on form2.

when I add f2.Show() , once I click the activate button on form1 , form2 will pop-up with red label back colour.

Please remember that I am running both form1 and form2 on my Mainform.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Please, show the code that loads the two separate forms.

Answer (score 0):

Your forms are just regular c# classes, and the form controls are private members of these classes.

If you need to have public access to few of those controls, just create a public property for those controls.

```
public Button MyColorButton 
{
    get { return MyButton; }
}
```